# rails test passing CSRF token only in get requests

Tags: ruby-on-rails, unit-testing, testing, devise, csrf

I'm trying to unit-test my controllers, every test that uses the `get` request works fine, but the tests where I use other calls (`delete` in destroy, `post` in create and `put` in update) fail with a:

```
WARNING: Can't verify CSRF token authenticity
Completed 401 Unauthorized in 2.5ms
```

for example this is the test for destroy:

```
  test "should destroy blog" do
    assert_difference('Blog.count', -1) do
      delete :destroy, id: @blog
    end

    assert_redirected_to blogs_path
  end
```

which doesn't work

and this is the test for show, which works:

```
  test "should show blog" do
    get :show, id: @blog
    assert_response :success
  end
```

in the destroy test the devise `authenticate_user!` just redirects me to the sign_in page and the test fails.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Apparently it's a normal thing to disable the CSRF token in the test environment, 
I added:

```
  # Disable request forgery protection in test environment
  config.action_controller.allow_forgery_protection    = false
```

to my "/config/environments/test.rb" file and the current user was able to pass through.

Comment: In my experience, you may have to add this setting to your `test_helper.rb` as well. See https://stackoverflow.com/q/60940695/1196465

Comment: What if you don't want to disable CSRF in controller unit tests? Do you have to use Devise?

Answer (score 2):

To get by `authenticate_user!`, you'll need to include and use the Devise test helpers as shown here:

https://github.com/plataformatec/devise#test-helpers

```
class ActionController::TestCase
  include Devise::TestHelpers
end
```

And use them in your tests:

```
  test "should show blog" do
    @user = users(:one) # or FactoryGirl.create(:user), or User.create!(email: 'foo@bar.com')
    sign_in @user
    get :show, id: @blog
    assert_response :success
  end
```

As for the CSRF Token, is your form built using `form_for` or some other form-builder?

These automatically add the CSRF token to your form payload. If you are writing your forms with bare `<form>` tag markup, you'll have to add it to the form yourself like this:

```
<%= hidden_field_tag :authenticity_token, form_authenticity_token %>
```

Comment: Thanks, I have the inclusion of devise in my app, and that's why the `get` requests work fine, the csrf token does work fine in my forms and views (which I generate with simple_forms gem) but because the unit tests don't pass through the browser the token is missing and the test fails. I need a way either to pass the token or to exclude the check when I'm testing.

Comment: You could put this in application_controller.rb: `skip_before_filter :verify_authenticity_token if Rails.env.test?`

Comment: I actually just figured that I can configure the test environment not to `config.action_controller.allow_forgery_protection    = false` which is mcuh better, once done this I'm not getting any more the CSRF warning, but I'm still getting the `Completed 401 Unauthorized`, so I guess the problem was not in the CSRF.... I'm clueless again.

Comment: Actually I correct myself, it seems that disabling the CRSF from the test environment worked. Some of the calls that weren't working previously now work, and with the others now I have different issues.. thanks for the support.