# How is a test throwing InvalidAuthenticityToken when forgery protection is disabled in the test environment?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, minitest

In my `ApplicationController`, I have set:

```rb
protect_from_forgery with: :exception
```

In my `config/environments/test.rb`, I have set:

```rb
config.action_controller.allow_forgery_protection = false
```

My understanding is that this should prevent authenticity token checking. But when running my tests, my non-`GET` requests result in:

```
Minitest::UnexpectedError: ActionController::InvalidAuthenticityToken
```

If I comment out `protect_from_forgery with: :exception`, I no longer get the `InvalidAuthenticityToken` exception.

**How could I be getting `InvalidAuthenticityToken` if `allow_forgery_protection` is set to `false`?**

**UPDATE:** I know I can disable protection when running tests by using `protect_from_forgery with: :exception unless Rails.env.test?`. I'm asking why my attempt to disable it in my test environment config via `allow_forgery_protection = false` doesn't work.

Comment: What's in your test_helper.rb file?

Comment: @ellitt My `test_helper.rb` file contains (1) `SimpleCov` initialization, (2) the three lines `ENV['RAILS_ENV'] ||= 'test'`, `require_relative '../config/environment'`, and `require 'rails/test_help'`, and (3) `class ActiveSupport::TestCase` with a `login_for_tests` method that does a login via my `SessionsController`. The `SessionsController` has `skip_before_action :verify_authenticity_token, only: :create`, so it should ignore the auth token, as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Took me a while to figure this out as I was having a similar issue.

It seems like the config was not being respected for some reason or another but putting this in your test_helper.rb should help:

```
ApplicationController.allow_forgery_protection = false
```